# Проблема с многопоточным клиент-серверным приложением на Java

Tags: java, javafx, клиент-сервер

Проблема заключается в том, что когда 2 пользователя работают параллельно, на клиенте приложение подвисает и на серваке 2 пользователя disconnected, в чем может быть проблема?
На стороне сервера:

```
public class Main  {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 1880;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        System.out.println("Port: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        while(true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            count++;
            ServerThread socketServerThread = new ServerThread(socket, count);
            socketServerThread.start();
            System.out.println("Client " + count);
        }
    }
}

public class ServerThread<T> extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private InetAddress addr;
    private static ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private int count;
    private String typeOfMessage = "";
    private Investor object;
    private BuildingCompany buildingCompany;
    private ShareBuilding shareBuilding;

    private ArrayList<BuildingCompany> buildingCompanies;
    private ArrayList<Investor> investorArrayList;
    private ArrayList<ShareBuilding> shareBuildings;

    private ShareBuildingDAO shareBuildingDAO;
    private InvestorDAO investorDAO;
    private BuildingCompanyDAO buildingCompanyDAO;

    private BuildObject buildObject;
    private BuildObjectDAO buildObjectDAO;
    private ArrayList<BuildObject> buildObjects;

    private Autorization autorization;

    ServerThread(Socket s, int c) throws IOException {
        socket = s;
        count = c;

        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        autorization = new Autorization();

        investorDAO = new InvestorDAO();
        investorArrayList = new ArrayList<Investor>();

        buildingCompanyDAO = new BuildingCompanyDAO();
        buildingCompanies = new ArrayList<BuildingCompany>();
        buildingCompany = new BuildingCompany();

        shareBuildings = new ArrayList<ShareBuilding>();
        shareBuildingDAO = new ShareBuildingDAO();

        buildObject = new BuildObject();
        buildObjects = new ArrayList<BuildObject>();
        buildObjectDAO = new BuildObjectDAO();

        addr = s.getInetAddress();
    }

    public static<T> ArrayList<T> receiveArrayListData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<T> ob = (ArrayList<T>)objectInputStream.readObject();
        return ob;
    }

    public static<T> void sendArrayListData(ArrayList<T> ob) throws IOException {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
    }

    public static<T> T receiveData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        T ob = (T)objectInputStream.readObject();
        return ob;
    }

    public static<T> void sendData(T ob) throws IOException {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
        objectOutputStream.reset();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String result = "", type = "";
        try {
            while (true) {
                typeOfMessage = (String)objectInputStream.readObject();
                switch (typeOfMessage) {
                    case "GetKnowType":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        String log = receiveData();
                        String pas = receiveData();
                        type = autorization.getType(log, pas);
                        System.out.println(type);
                        sendData(type);
                        break;
                    case "LoginPassword":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        String l = receiveData();
                        String p = receiveData();
                        Object ob = autorization.check(l, p);
                        sendData(ob);
                        break;
                    case "Registration":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        InformationUsers.setObject(receiveData());
                        result = investorDAO.add(InformationUsers.getObject());
                        sendData(result);
                        break;
                    case "ShowUserFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        investorArrayList = investorDAO.getInvestorList();
                        sendData(investorArrayList);
                        break;
                    case "DeleteUserFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        InformationUsers.setObject(receiveData());
                        investorDAO.delete(InformationUsers.getObject());
                        break;
                    case "UpdateUserInDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        investorArrayList = receiveArrayListData();
                        investorDAO.update(investorArrayList);
                        break;
                    case "AddDataBuildingCompany":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildingCompany = receiveData();
                        buildingCompanyDAO.add(buildingCompany);
                        break;
                    case "ShowBuildingCompanyFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildingCompanies = buildingCompanyDAO.getBuildingCompanyList();
                        sendArrayListData(buildingCompanies);
                        break;
                    case "DeleteBuildingCompanyFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildingCompany = receiveData();
                        buildingCompanyDAO.delete(buildingCompany);
                        break;
                    case "UpdateBuildingCompany":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildingCompanies = receiveArrayListData();
                        buildingCompanyDAO.update(buildingCompanies);
                        break;
                    case "RegistrationShareBuilding":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        InformationUsers.setShareBuilding(receiveData());
                        shareBuildingDAO.add(InformationUsers.getShareBuilding());
                        break;
                    case "ShareBuildingFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        shareBuildings = shareBuildingDAO.getShareBuildingCompanyList();
                        sendArrayListData(shareBuildings);
                        break;
                    case "DeleteShareBuildingFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        InformationUsers.setShareBuilding(receiveData());
                        shareBuildingDAO.delete(InformationUsers.getShareBuilding());
                        break;
                    case "UpdateShareBuildingInDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        shareBuildings = receiveArrayListData();
                        shareBuildingDAO.update(shareBuildings);
                        break;
                    case "ChangeAdminPassword":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        String pass = receiveData();
                        investorDAO.changeAdminPassword(pass);
                        break;
                    case "AddBuildObjectInDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        InformationUsers.getObject().setBuildObject(receiveData());
                        buildObjectDAO.add(InformationUsers.getObject().getBuildObject());
                        break;
                    case "DeleteBuildObjectInDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildObject = receiveData();
                        buildObjectDAO.delete(buildObject);
                        break;
                    case "UpdateBuildObjectInDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildObjects = receiveArrayListData();
                        buildObjectDAO.update(buildObjects);
                        break;
                    case "ShowBuildObjectFromDB":
                        System.out.println("Type of message: " + typeOfMessage + " from client #" + count);
                        buildObjects = buildObjectDAO.getBuildObjectList();
                        sendArrayListData(buildObjects);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Клиент #" + count + " disconnected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try{
            if (objectOutputStream != null) {
                objectOutputStream.close();
            }
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
                objectInputStream.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

На стороне клиента:

```
public class client<T>
{
    private static int port;
    private static String txtAddr;
    private static String typeOfMessage;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private static ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public client(String txtADdr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.txtAddr = txtADdr;
        this.port = port;
        socket = new Socket(this.txtAddr, this.port);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    public static <T> void sendDataArrayList(ArrayList<T> ob, String tMsg) throws IOException {

        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> void sendData(T ob, String tMsg) throws IOException {
                typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static<T> ArrayList<T> receiveArrayList(String tMsg) throws IOException {
        typeOfMessage = tMsg;

        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
            list = (ArrayList<T>)object;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //sendMessageExit();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static<T> Object sendLoginPassword(String l, String p, String tMsg) {
        Object object = null;
        String type = "";
        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(l);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(p);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
            object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }

    public static<T> String sendDataRegistration(T ob, String tMsg) {
        String response = "";

        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();

            response = (String)objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

}

public class connect
{
    private static String textAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    private static int textPort = 1880;

    public static void connect() throws IOException {
        client runnableClient = new client(textAddress, textPort);
        }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте сделать [mcve], а так же перестаньте использовать `static` так часто и там где это не нужно.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо за совет, учту

Comment: а пример добавите?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663551/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Comment: надо было этот вопрос исправить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает многопоточность в клиент-серверном приложении на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663551/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)